# sqlite - how to let registered users own collections?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to allow users registered to my database to have their own tables for various collections that are owned uniquely by their id.

The users are stored in: `(users :: id -> [id, email])`

```
create table users (
    id integer primary key autoincrement not null unique,
    email varchar[255] not null    
);
```

and they have a profile table:

```
create table profiles (
    id integer unique primary key not null,    
    foreign key(id) references users(id)
);
```

I want to be able to add various collections that the user profile could reference, such as friends list, favorite music names, and list of previously used password hashes.

My initial thinking was to create a unique table for each of these collections and relate a table-name field in profiles to the actual name of the table, but this idea seems really silly since it floods the database with many nonsensical named tables.

I also have a concern that even though I can create a table for each collection, I have no idea how to reference a table named by a field in another table in SQL, so I would need to perform two queries and process the first before passing it on to second.

1. get the collection id from the profiles table.
2. access a table named the result of query 1.

Which feels wrong as well.

Is there another approach for mapping primary key to a collection-of-things than creating a table? And if not, should I be using different databases such as "friend_lists.db" for storing all of these tables?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that dynamically creating tables is "weird". I've seen many people on Stack Overflow try to use this anti-pattern.

Whatever you were about to parameterize your table names with, move to a column in a single table.

For example, if you were thinking about using this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user_1234_music(track_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE user_5678_music(track_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE user_5483_music(track_name TEXT);
-- and so on
```

Move the user ID to a column, with a foreign key constraint to ensure it points to a valid user.

```
CREATE TABLE friends(user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id), track_name TEXT);
```

This has several benefits:

- No popular SQL database engine supports using query parameters in table names, meaning you would have to use string manipulation to "pass" in the value to the table name, exposing you to SQL injection vulnerabilities.
- Most database do not have a way to dynamically select between different table names based on query results. Columns are easy to filter, either in `WHERE` or `JOIN` clauses.
- Schema changes (adding/removing columns, indexes, constraints, etc) only have to happen on one table.
- Databases are built to scale to millions of rows. They are not as well equipped to scale with large amounts of tables (or columns for that matter).

Comment: Let me see if I understand you  correctly. Are you suggesting to store the friends list in a single table, and filter it by whose friends you are searching for? eg Bob's friends and Amy's friends are in the same table but when you are looking for Bob's friends, you search for rows by Bob's id.

Comment: It just feels that moving this data to json file mapping id to all friend ids would be more computationally efficient since I am not sure if the database somehow skips the "loop over millions of rows to find this guy's 100 friends" and optimizes it to something more sensible, whereas since the relationship is simply number -> many numbers, it feels it's wrong to just put all friends in one table.

Comment: @Dmitry That is exactly it. `SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = bobs_id`. You can also use joins: `SELECT users.name FROM friends INNER JOIN users ON users.id = friends.friend_id WHERE friends.user_id = bobs_id` (can't do that if you are using JSON). If you have an index set up on the columns you frequently query, the search will be fast.

Comment: So you are saying if the table is (friends :: whose_friend[many] -> friend[many])*naive*, with no primary key, and I somehow index it by whose_friend, then it performs some kind of indexing magic to make it not loop over the whole table every time to find the friends for a single user? I guess I need to read http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-an-index/ or something. Seems to work similarly to hash buckets in a naive sense.

Comment: So you reccomend me to do something like this: http://hastebin.com/bofuvozapo.sql ?

Comment: @Dmitry Do your users need more than one password? If not, then put the password column in the `users` table. You might also want to either make a multi-column primary key over both columns of the `friends` table or make a unique index over the same columns to ensure that you don't have duplicate entries. Other than that, it looks good.

Comment: only one password but in this experiment I want to demonstrate ability to store past password hashes as an imperfect password recovery means. By the way, once I create the index, the select statements take it into account by default right? Or do I need to access the index in a special way?